# Xbee to act as wireless i/o extension

Tags: arduino, sensor, wireless, xbee

I want to have an *arduino* with an xbee (call it *xbee1*) connected to it and another wireless xbee (call it *xbee2*) communicating with *xbee1*. Then I would have DIO1 on *xbee2* acting as a digital input and DIO1 on *xbee1* acting as an output outputting exactly the input on *xbee2*'s DIO1. Then to be able to do this with more xbees (eg *xbee3*)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7sDOi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this a possibility? Also if so does it matter what series of xbee I use?
Could you also please explain how to do this.
I have spent a lot of time googling but I cannot find anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Each xbee has a set destination address. In xbee2 and xbee3 you would set the destination address to that of xbee1.

Yes it matters what series you use. For this, use xbee series 1 because series 2 xbees do not support automatic DIO line passing. You can use series 2 but they would have to operate in API mode, and instead of the xbee2 and 3 automatically transmitting when they see a change on a DIO line, arduino/xbee1 would have to poll xbee2/3 to determine the DIO line status.

Comment: Thanks, thats more what I was looking for. I think that I'll go with series 1 then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This answer just relates to what you have to take care of and how I would approach it.

The system you describe is like a bunch of remote temperature measurment (or alarm) devices all reporting back to a central point. With the radio system you propose, you can transmit and receive so if you have many "remote" devices, they can be treated as "slaves" that can be polled from the "master" and then transmit their information to the master. This keeps the system from having to cope with data collisions. Obviously each slave needs an address so it knows when it is being requested to return its info or data.

There are, however, simpler radio systems (especially if the "slaves" are battery powered) that have a one-way communication method - this saves battery life in the slaves - they do not have a receiver and therefore can only transmit and hope for the best that the master receives the data they sent. Typically for (say) a remote temperature monitoring system (freezers in a shop) the slave transmits every 10 minutes. The transmission is performed in less than 1 second and, if there are ten freezers each transmitting every ten minutes, collisions are unlikely. **BUT** you have to build a random factor in each slaves timing so that if collisions do occur they are unlikely to occur the next time the slave transmits.

So you have a choice based on how much data you need to receive and how often you want to receive it. You need to think about this.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. I feel that I understand this a little more thoroughly. However, could you possibly point me to a tutorial and which series would you recommend that I choose? Thanks, I would upvote this answer but I don't have the reputation points.

Comment: @ohope5 - I've never used xbee so other folk would do better than me in recommendations